# faiss.normalize_L2(embeddings) gives the distances in a range of 212.0 when index.Search() is executed

Tags: faiss

index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(vectormatrix.shape[1])

print(index.is_trained)

faiss.normalize_L2(vectormatrix)

index.add(vectormatrix)

print(index.ntotal)

Distance, Index = index.Search(token_vector.reshape((1,token_vector.size)), k)

Comment: https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/why-you-should-be-careful-using-faiss-c44996eda9ee

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same issue, but with inner product. Distance should be in range (-1; 1), but I have values like 100 or 200.

```
%%time
k = 255

dim = X.shape[1]
quantiser = faiss.IndexFlatIP(dim)
index = faiss.IndexIVFFlat(quantiser, dim, k)

faiss.normalize_L2(X)

index.train(X)
index.add(X)

sample = ['some text']
query = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray(vectorizer.transform(sample))
index.nprobe=100
D, I = index.search(query, 10)
print(D[0])

> array([73.49516 , 73.504524, 73.75489 , 73.767204, 73.78795 ,
> 73.800064, 73.80722 , 73.82175 , 73.94714 , 74.034   ], dtype=float32)
```

Im trying to solve this now

adding as an argument `faiss.METRIC_INNER_PRODUCT` to `faiss.IndexIVFFlat()` partially solved my problem

UPDATE:

add

```
faiss.normalize_L2(query)
```

after

```
query = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray(vectorizer.transform(sample))
```

After these changes you will get the correct distance value